# How to create a node (if not exists) with in Neo4j

Tags: node.js, database, neo4j, nosql, cypher

I am trying to make a system where an admin can push a `blogPost` to the front page. I use Neo4j to save the Mongo ID's of these objects (not the best way but I'm forced by school to use both Neo4j and MongoDB).

Now I have made a query and it works, it saves the admin, the blogpost, and the `added_by` relation. The problem is that it creates the admin, blogpost whether or not they already exist. How can I solve this? My graph is now a mess.

[image: Sample graph]

This is my Node.js route and query:

```
routes.post('/blogPosts/frontpage/:id/:aid', function (req, res) {
  const id = req.param('id');
  const aid = req.param('aid');

  session
    .run("CREATE(n:BlogPost {mongoId:{idNeo}}), (b:Admin {mongoAdminId:{idNeoAd}})", {idNeo: id, idNeoAd: aid});
    session
    .run("MATCH (u:BlogPost {mongoId:{idNeo}}), (r:Admin {mongoAdminId:{idNeoAd}}) CREATE (u)-[:ADDED_BY]->(r)", {idNeo: id, idNeoAd: aid})
    .then(function(result) {
      res.status(200).json({"response": "BlogPost added to front page."});
      session.close();
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      res.status(400).json(error);
    });
});
```

How can I change my route to only add the admin/post if they don't exist yet?

**EDIT:**

```
session.run("CREATE (u:BlogPost {mongoId:{idNeo}}), (r:Admin {mongoAdminId:{idNeoAd}}) CREATE UNIQUE(u)-[:ADDED_BY]->(r)", {idNeo: id, idNeoAd: aid})
```

This fixes the mess but still creates the nodes even if they exist.

Now I get a semantic error in my query (in the session.run)

```
routes.post('/blogPosts/frontpage/:id/:aid', function (req, res) {
  const id = req.param('id');
  const aid = req.param('aid');

    session
    .run("MERGE (n:BlogPost {mongoId:{idNeo}}) MERGE (b:Admin {mongoAdminId:{idNeoAd}}) CREATE UNIQUE(u)-[:ADDED_BY]->(r)", {idNeo: id, idNeoAd: aid})
    .then(function(result) {
      res.status(200).json({"response": "BlogPost added to front page."});
      session.close();
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      res.status(400).json(error);
    });
});
```

Comment: I now have this, which creates seperate nodes and relations but it still adds if even if it exists.
session
    .run("CREATE (u:BlogPost {mongoId:{idNeo}}), (r:Admin {mongoAdminId:{idNeoAd}}) CREATE UNIQUE(u)-[:ADDED_BY]->(r)", {idNeo: id, idNeoAd: aid})

Comment: I think you are searching the `MERGE` command :  http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/merge/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, use [MERGE](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/merge/) instead of CREATE. The docs about MERGE says:

> The MERGE clause ensures that a pattern exists in the graph. Either
>   the pattern already exists, or it needs to be created.

TRY Changing your query to:

```
MERGE (n:BlogPost {mongoId:{idNeo}}) MERGE (b:Admin {mongoAdminId:{idNeoAd}})
```

Comment: Like this?
`MERGE (n:BlogPost {mongoId:{idNeo}}) MERGE (b:Admin {mongoAdminId:{idNeoAd}}) CREATE UNIQUE(u)-[:ADDED_BY]->(r)`

Comment: I put the two queries together in one sentence as you can see in the edit

Comment: It gives me an error, I think I messed up the query.
`{
    "code": "Neo.ClientError.Statement.SemanticError",
    "name": "Neo4jError"
}`

Comment: @Mike Can you post here the exact js line that is throwing the error?

Comment: It gives me no further info, but I think I know where it is, I will post it in the edit!

Comment: I posted my new route, the problem should be in the session.run (in the cypher query)

Comment: Could you please look into this? I'm having a lot of trouble with this problem

Comment: @Mike change `CREATE UNIQUE` to `MERGE`. This way: `MERGE (n:BlogPost {mongoId:{idNeo}}) MERGE (b:Admin {mongoAdminId:{idNeoAd}}) MERGE (u)-[:ADDED_BY]->(r)`

Comment: @Mike note that CREATE UNIQUE is deprecated / removed. See [this link](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/deprecations-additions-removals-compatibility/#cypher-deprecations-additions-removals-3.2).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161203/discussion-between-bruno-peres-and-mike).